# JAVA - Cassandra Set Batch Size

Tags: java, cassandra, key-value-store

I am creating a key-value store in Cassandra with the Java driver and it is complaining about the batch size being too big.

So I want to reduce the Cassandra batch size. I have a BatchStatement object which contains a setFetchSize method. Is this the appropriate method to set the batch size. Otherwise, how can I do it?

thanks in advance

Altober

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch statements are useful but they are not maded for bulk loading in Cassandra, in the [C# faq](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.7/csharp-driver/csdFaq.html) Datastax clearly recommend to have a batch size in the order of tens.

If you want to insert a lot of datas, [the best practise](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/) is to use regular or [async statements](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/asynchronous_t.html) to do so.